# How to apply FP-Growth to dataset after groupBy?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-2.0

I'd like to use FP-Growth from Spark MLlib in Spark 2.1.

My data has only two columns `item_group` and `item`.

[image: dataset]

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
sc = SparkSession.builder.appName("Assoziationsanalyse").getOrCreate()
hiveCtx = SQLContext(sc)

input = hiveCtx.sql("""select  * from bosch.input_view""").
  groupBy("item_group").
  agg(collect_list("item")).
  alias("items").
  rdd.
  map(lambda x : x.items)

model = FPGrowth.train(input, minSupport=0.2, numPartitions=10)
```

Comment: Given your dataset it appears that `item_group` is unique. Is that correct? In this particular case, `groupBy` + `collect_list` would be a simple transformation to create an array column that FPGrowth expects.

Comment: `item_group` represents a shopping cart, in the table above it is coincidentally that each `item_group` appears only once.

Comment: Can you paste a more insightful dataset for future reference? Please paste the dataset (not screenshot it).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem now using an other approch which I have found in a discussion here.

```
data=hiveCtx.sql("""select  * from bosch.input_view""")

datardd=data.rdd.map(lambda x (x[0],x[1])).groupByKey().mapValues(list).values()

model = FPGrowth.train(datardd, minSupport=0.1, numPartitions=10)
```

Comment: Why are you using RDD (`data.rdd`)? What version of Spark do you use? The code above can be very ineffective (due to leaving Dataset optimizations aside and `groupByKey`).

Comment: @JacekLaskowski cannot use map on a DataFrame. I am using Spark 2.1. As mentioned before I am very new at programming and especially spark. And since FP-Growth is in MLlib and not in ML it works with RDD and cannot work with DataFrame? Sorry if I am telling wrong things but that is what I thought.

Comment: Correct. FPGrowth does not seem available for DataFrames, but you could at least prepare the data using Dataset API and only at the very end (before training a model) leave it for RDD API.